# No response when trying to publish the project on to the WAS Server

Tags: websphere

I have imported a project into the eclipse and it has different modules like

- Audit
- AuditEJB
- Common
- CommonLoginConsumer
- Core
- Db2Integration
- EJB
- InitWeb
- Integration EAR
- MDMIntegration
- PrepackagedApps
- Properties
- SchedulerEJB
- ScreensWeb
- WebServiceConsumer
- WebServiceProvider
- Provider
- CCWSTest (Gradle module)
- CTest
- CUiWeb
- UtilityTestEAR
- UtilityTestWeb

Configured build Path, solved all the Java Problems. In the company that I'm working to configure WAS Server 8.0, we need to configure DSC which has all the deployment frameworks.

In Servers (Right click)> Add and Remove, I have **IntegrationEAR** and **UtilityTestEAR**

- **UtilityTestEAR** contains *Properties, and UtilityTestWeb*
- **Integration EAR** has *apsclient-source.jar, Adit, AuditEJB, Common, CommonLoginConsumer, Core, Db2Integration, EJB, InitWeb, MDMIntegration, Properties, SchedulerEJB, ScreensWeb, WebServiceConsumer, WebServiceProvider, Provider, org.apache.soap.encoding61.jar*
- **When I added UtilityTestEAR** to the WAS Server, **Server started Successfully and when I try to publish there was no response.**
- **When I added IntegrationEAR** to the WAS Server, when I started the server, **there was an error saying:**
  The publish encountered some problems and the application may not have been installed or it may have been successfully installed but was unable to start.
  The application contains validation errors. Correct the errors in the Problems view before publishing the application on the server. 
  If you want to allow applications containing errors to be published on the server, enable the Allow applications containing errors to be published on a server check box (Windows > Preferences > Servers > WebSphere).
  CHKJ2802E:  class com.ford.mss.cdr.cib.mdb.CdrAuditLogMDB, or one of its supertypes, cannot be reflected. Check the classpath.

**I am trying to deploy to my localhost.**

Please Suggest

Comment: I don't understand what is there to downvote this question of mine. I tried some ways and didn't work out and looking for suggestions/help. Isn't this stackoverflow is for that?

Comment: I would recommend adding was/websphere tags and removing java.